# Are 'speaking' and 'desert' related in Hebrew?

Tags: hebrew, dor-hamidbar

"Bamidbar" means "In the desert" or "In the wilderness".  But the root dalet/bet/resh also refers to speaking.  Are the two related, and if so, how?

(This is not purely a grammar question.  Is there a relation between God giving us the Torah in the wilderness and the act of speaking?)

Comment: Hoshea 2:16-17 appears to use the pun הַמִּדְבָּ֑ר וְדִבַּרְתִּ֖י alluding to Yisrael's exodus from Mitsrayim to receive HaTorah.

Comment: Rabbi Sacks z"l - https://rabbisacks.org/covenant-conversation-5768-bemidbar-the-wilderness-and-the-word-2/